# Isometry groups acting transitively

Tags: metric-geometry, topological-groups, group-actions, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space and $G$ be its group of isometries.

1) Is it true that $G$ acts on $X$ transitively? If so, where can I find a proof? If not, how can one characterize those $X$ for which the action is transitive?

2) It is known that if $X$ is (locally-)compact then $G$ is a (locally-)compact topological group (with the compact-open topology). The proof that I know is in volume 1 of Kobayashi & Nomizu and consists of 6 lemmae, 1 theorem and 3 corollaries, stretching on 4 pages. Does anyone know of a shorter proof?

Comment: Concerning (1), this is almost never true. E.g., take any non-discrete space $Y$ of diameter $1$ and add an extra point $x_0$ at distance $1$ from everything else. Then $x_0$ is not conjugate to any limit point of $Y$. Or take a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and add a point not in its closure. The space should be very homogeneous to have transitive isometry group.

Comment: 1) is certainly not true in general: the group of isometries of $[0,1]$ is $\Bbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: For the nonpositive curvature case see http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/273/art%253A10.1007%252FBF01344139.pdf?auth66=1396358835_c13b70040b3c1b8697c40fb49deaacbf&ext=.pdf and the references cited therein.

Comment: My feeling about the Kobayashi/Nomizu proof is that it is the length that it is because they fill in lots of details. One can always shorten a proof by omitting details, for example "It is a consequence of the Ascoli-Arzela theorem. QED."

Comment: Actually for the non-positively-curved case, there is a frightening amount known: http://egg.epfl.ch/~nmonod/articles/structure.pdf (Caprace + Monod).

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev The space should just be homogeneous (by definition).

Comment: By what definition? Actually, the only reasonable definition of "homogeneous" is $1$-transitive :)

Comment: It's not true that if $X$ is locally compact then so is $Isom(X)$ with compact open topology. Example: $X$ countable set with all distances $=1$.

Comment: @YCor: Indeed, $X$ must have finitely many connected components.

Comment: @LeeMosher: After having attempted to come up with a proof based on the Arzela-Ascoli theorem, I discovered that it is the pointwise relative compactness of $Isom(G)$ that raises problems. It $X$ is complete and length-metric (or compact), then things are easy with the Hopf-Rinow theorem. If not, then the proof of the pointwise relative compactness essentially boils down to what is done in Kobayashi & Nomizu.